# Cassandra Input Step, Pentaho Spoon: Read a negative frame size

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, kettle

Any query with any configuration with **Cassandra Input** step in Pentaho Spoon throws this exception (Cassandra version is 2.0.8 with default configuration):

```
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : Error desconocido
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 - Read a negative frame size (-2113929216)!
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 - Read a negative frame size (-2113929216)!
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 - 
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInput.processRow(CassandraInput.java:178)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 - Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2113929216)!
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:133)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:362)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:284)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:191)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_set_cql_version(Cassandra.java:1855)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.set_cql_version(Cassandra.java:1842)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.CassandraConnection.checkOpen(CassandraConnection.java:159)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.CassandraConnection.setKeyspace(CassandraConnection.java:174)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.LegacyKeyspace.setKeyspace(LegacyKeyspace.java:100)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.CassandraConnection.getKeyspace(CassandraConnection.java:277)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInput.processRow(CassandraInput.java:175)
2014/06/27 10:08:47 - Cassandra Input.0 -   ... 2 more
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: are you able to connect with cassandra by clicking show-schema??

Comment: I am also facing the same issue do you have any solution. After reading 40000 rows I am getting the same error @WorkingHard..

Comment: you are using pentaho 5.1.0.0 only?

Comment: you can refer this link : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/FgHw9smmAI4

Comment: hi, I know this is a old question. But i am using pdi 7.0 with cql3 and I am facing the same exception. were you able to resolve this ?